# MYSQL query returning more values

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

The issue is I have DATA and SAT table that have 3 fields, each of these fields may contain value 991. The below does not give correct number of columns give more data. How to get correct value. Please advice

```
DATA

id
insurance1
insurance2
insurance3

SAT
id
insurance1
insurance2
insurance3

SELECT * FROM DATA v, SAT s where v.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID = '991' 
or v.INSURANCE_ID  = '991' 
or v.INSURANCE_ID = '991' 
and s.INSURANCE_ID = '991' 
or s.INSURANCE_ID = '991' 
or s.INSURANCE_ID = '991';
```

Let me give an example
Example 1

```
DATA    
    id
    insurance1 =991
    insurance2 =56
    insurance3 =22

    SAT
    id
    insurance1=56
    insurance2=23
    insurance3=96

When query is executed. The count should be 1
```

Example 2

```
DATA    
    id
    insurance1 =991
    insurance2 =56
    insurance3 =22

    SAT
    id
    insurance1=991
    insurance2=23
    insurance3=96

When query is executed. The count should be 2
```

Example 3

```
DATA    
    id
    insurance1 =991
    insurance2 =56
    insurance3 =991

    SAT
    id
    insurance1=991
    insurance2=23
    insurance3=96

When query is executed. The count should be 3 or 2
```

Comment: DATA

id
insurance1 =991
insurance2=56
insurance3=36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tables and you want to count 991 in them. So the tables are not necessarily related and a join makes no sense. Simply add the two counts:

```
select
  (select count(*) from data where 991 in (insurance1, insurance2, insurance3))
  +
  (select count(*) from sat where 991 in (insurance1, insurance2, insurance3));
```

BTW: Be carefull when mixing ANDs and ORs :-)

Comment: The query is not giving desired result.

Comment: So what result do you want? If you have 3 data records having 991 and 4 sat records having 991 it gives you 3 + 4 = 7. What number do you expect instead?

Comment: My apologies, you are correct this is returning the desired value and value. I miscalculated the number of rows. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rephrasing this as a `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA v JOIN
     SAT
     ON '991' in (v.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID, v.INSURANCE_ID) AND 
        '991' in (s.INSURANCE_ID)
```

Your query only mentions three fields.  You can extend the `in` list to have all the columns you want.  Based on your table structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA v JOIN
     SAT
     ON '991' in (v.INSURANCE1, v.INSURANCE2, v.INSURANCE3) AND 
        '991' in (s.INSURANCE1, s.INSURANCE2, s.INSURANCE3);
```

EDIT:

I don't think you want a `join` at all:

```
select count(*), count(distinct id)
from (select id, insurance1 as insurance from data union all
      select id, insurance2 from data union all
      select id, insurance3 from data union all
      select id, insurance1 from sat union all
      select id, insurance2 from sat union all
      select id, insurance3 from sat
     ) i
where insurance = '991';
```

Use `count(*)` to get 3 and `count(distinct id)` to get 2.  Note:  the latter assumes that the `id`s match between the tables.

Comment: This returns zero records even though DATA insurance1 has value 991. Please advice

Comment: This requires that each table has `991` in one of the columns.  So, I would guess that there are no such rows in `SAT`.

Comment: There may or may not have 991 is both the table. I have edited the question with example. In that scenario what do you suggest.

Comment: In my opinion this would be better readable with using CROSS JOIN and moving the criteria to the WHERE clause, because you cross join all 991 records. Thus one would become aware of the risk when it comes to counting.